# Implementing a Blacklist of keywords in SQL

Tags: sql, blacklist

I have a list of keywords (strings) in which I need to identify any matches with a blacklist of keywords (strings in a separate table)

Any keyword/blacklist matches will be flagged in a bit field: Keyword.IsBlacklisted.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this in SQL?

The matches might be partial (i.e. blacklist = 'sex' keyword = 'sex toy')

**SOLUTION - Thanks Daniel Spiewak**

```
 SELECT Keyword.Keyword FROM Keyword CROSS JOIN BlackList
 WHERE (Keyword.Keyword 
 LIKE { fn CONCAT({ fn CONCAT('%', BlackList.Keyword) }, '%') })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT keyword FROM words JOIN blacklist 
               WHERE keyword LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%', word), '%')
```

Assuming that the words are in the `keyword` field of the `words` table and the `blacklist` contains its words in the `word` field.  This will be anything but efficient, but I think it's the best you can do from a theoretical standpoint.

Comment: Got to be better than pulling the information out and programmically manipulating the data

Comment: SELECT     Keyword.KeywordName
FROM         Keyword CROSS JOIN
                      BlackList
WHERE     (Keyword.KeywordName LIKE { fn CONCAT({ fn CONCAT('%', BlackList.BlackList) }, '%') })